# How to focus on popover when it pop without clicking it?

Tags: reactjs, antd, popover

I'm trying to create a popover that automatically focuses. Instead of click the popover window I want the mouse cursor to focus it when it pop without the need to click it.

- I tried to add attr of `autoFocus={true}` in  `<Select` but it didn't work as well.

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { Select, Popover } from "antd";
const { Option } = Select;

export default function App() {
  function ButtonActions() {
    function onChange(value) {
      console.log(value);
    }

    function onBlur() {
      // console.log('blur');
    }

    function onFocus() {
      // console.log('focus');
    }

    function onSearch(val) {
      // console.log('search:', val);
    }

    return (
      <Select
        //why autoFocus don't work?
        autoFocus={true}
        showSearch
        bordered={false}
        onChange={onChange}
        onFocus={onFocus}
        onBlur={onBlur}
        onSearch={onSearch}
        filterOption={(input, option) =>
          option.children.indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0
        }
        defaultValue="options"
        style={{ width: 120 }}
      >
        <Option className="btn btn-danger" value="delete">
          option
        </Option>
      </Select>
    );
  }

  const content = (
    <div>
      <ButtonActions />
    </div>
  );
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Popover placement="topLeft" trigger="click" content={content}>
        <div>click me</div>
      </Popover>
      <div>don't click</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`also you can find the code on` https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-voice-fehyo?file=/src/App.js:0-1251